# How to start with WebSocket implementations

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, websocket

Team,

If project is using `J2SE/SPRING/TOMCAT` on server side; 

 
Q1) Do i really need `J2EE` ; to support websocket on our server side? Or Can i use `APACHE` WebSocket implementation (which doesn't require J2EE ...?)

Q2) Why; java websocket specification/API implementation added as part of J2EE? not in J2SE ..?

Q3) I could see; APACHE/lib dir has `servlet-api.jar` which contains J2EE classes; this is why we dont need J2EE installation on the server for APACHE WebSocket ?

Q4) do APACHE really extended ORACLE javax.websocket API while implementing their WebSocket?
Since i could not see JAVA API usage on their implementations. I think APACHE implemented their WebSocket by their own; without using JAVA (javax.websocket.*) package ?

```
org.apache.tomcat.websocket
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server
```

[TOMCAT_DOC](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/index.html?org/apache/catalina/websocket/WebSocketServlet.html)
[JAVA_DOC](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A1. Java WebSocket 1.0 is one if many specifications that make up Java EE 7. Apache Tomcat 7 and Apache Tomcat 8 both include a JSR-356 (Java WebSocket 1.0) implementation. There is no need for a full Java EE container.

A2. The client part of Java WebSocket will probably move to Java SE at some point.

A3. Every Java EE specification has two parts. The API and the implementation. The API will be the same on every container. The implementations are usually different. You need both to to be present in order for the implementation to work. servlet-api.jar has nothing to do with Java WebSocket. servlet-api.jar is the JAR that ships with Apache Tomcat that contains the API for the Java Servlet specification. The Java WebSocket API is in websocket-api.jar

A4. Yes, Apache Tomcat ships with an implementation of Java WebSocket 1.0. You are looking at the packages for the implementation classes. If you look at the source for the classes in those packages you will see that they implementation the Java WebSocket 1.0 API which is defined in the javax.websocket and javax.websocket.server packages.

If you need some pointers about where to get started, take a look at the WebSocket examples that ship with Tomcat.

Comment: Do i need j2ee jre for Tomcat 7...?

Comment: The minimum requirement for Apache Tomcat 7 is a Java 6 or later JRE. You can use a Java 6 or later JDK if you prefer. There is no requirement for a Java EE installation.

Comment: I could see APACHE websocket implementation is using J2EE code <code>"org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" </code> http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/index.html?org/apache/catalina/websocket/WebSocketServlet.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring-WebSocket which also lets you use SockJS which is a reliable fallback options for clients that don't support websocket with just a simple one line configuration. (Check http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html)

Or

You can use Websocket implementation as provided by Tomcat libraries.

Either way you don't need J2EE. 
You can use Tomcat 7.0.52 + or Tomcat

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/index.html?org/apache/catalina/websocket/WebSocketServlet.html shows apache is using javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet which is j2EE code ..?

Comment: That has been part of all previous tomcat version under servlet-api.jar, hence you can use it in your code but you don't need to install J2EE jdk separately.